# R ESS Plotting on Ubuntu - How to enable plotting history (or work around)

Tags: r, ubuntu, plot, ess

I have been using ESS on Mac in the past and when I plotted repeatedly, I was able to access and **navigate between plots** using the arrow keys (if I remember correctly). A plotting history is also implemented in RStudio and I would like to use or emulate this feature using ESS on my Ubuntu machine. Is there any way to do this (through installing packages, using other Devices, etc.)?

*And if this should not be possible*: What is your workflow, when producing multiple plots in exploratory analysis?

Comment: I've read the following discussion, but hopefully there are other solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838851/how-to-copy-plots-in-r-when-working-in-ubuntu